# My Status bar isn't the same on androidstudio and on my smartphone

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an application and I have an issue

On my smartphone (Xperia Z3) I have a transparent status bar with a shadow at the top.
On the android studio emulator, I have a semi-transparent status bar

I would like to have the same android studio status bar (a semi-transparent status bar) on my xperia Z3.

I am using this code :

http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html

(On the emulator, I have the same status bar as shown in the link)

Comment: What is version of Adnroid on your device and emulator?

Comment: my xperia Z3 : 5.0.2
on emulator it seems to be lollipop as well

Comment: Unfortunately Sony have their own vision of how Android should look and work. There is realy not much you can do about it.

Comment: yes but my gmail application have the good status bar

Answer (score 0):

as Alex already said that maybe Sony have their own UI look, still you can try this code if it works..!

```
 ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    assert mActionBar != null;
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.mOrange)));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.Any_Color_You_Want));
    }
```